# Swift enumerated equivalent in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

In a 3x3 matrix representation, i can find the sum of both diagonals with one liners in `Swift` as below,

```
let array = [
   [1, 2, 3],
   [4, 5, 6],
   [-7, 8, 9]
]
let d1 = array.enumerated().map({ $1[$0] }).reduce(0, +)
let d2 = array.reversed().enumerated().map({ $1[$0] }).reduce(0, +)
print(d1) // prints 15
print(d2) // prints 1
```

I am able to find `map` and `reduce` equivalents in `Kotlin` as `flatMap` and `fold` but couldn't find for `enumerated`.

How can we achieve similar with higher order functions in `Kotlin`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting with this input:

```
val input: Array<Array<Int>> = arrayOf(
        arrayOf(1, 2, 3),
        arrayOf(4, 5, 6),
        arrayOf(-7, 8, 9)
)
```

this is how I'd phrase the diagonal sums:

```
val mainDiagonalSum = input.indices
        .map { input[it][it] }
        .reduce(Int::plus)
val counterDiagonalSum = input.indices
        .map { input[input.size - 1 - it][it] }
        .reduce(Int::plus)
```

Note that this is an improvement over your solution because it doesn't have to create the reversed array. It improves the time complexity from O(n<sup>2</sup>) to O(n).

If you're dealing with large matrices, it would pay to reduce the space complexity from O(n) to O(1) as well, by using `fold` instead of `reduce`:

```
val mainDiagonalSum = input.indices
        .fold(0) { sum, i -> sum + input[i][i] }
val counterDiagonalSum = input.indices
        .fold(0) { sum, i -> sum + input[input.size - 1 - i][i] }
```

Comment: `fold` is also important if you have empty arrays. I often find myself using `fold` instead of `reduce` in 99% of the cases.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're looking for [withIndex](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/with-index.html)

Answer (score 0):

this works for me nearly the same as Swift's version

```
fun <T> List<T>.enumerated(): List<Pair<Int, T>> {
    return this.indices.map { Pair(it, this[it]) }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**